# Vertical alignment of text phrases of different font size

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, line-spacing, glue

(With 2. and 3. "line 001", "line 002" etc at the left are only to show that the baselines of the lines at the right have vertical distances that are multiples of `\baselineskip` of the normalfont in normalsize.)

1. What is the best/least cumbersome way of ensuring that phrases typeset in two different font sizes are aligned so that the rules that delimit the top of ascenders of the letters of the larger font are at the height of the rules that delimit the top of the ascenders of the smaller font like in the following picture?

   [image]
2. What is the best/least cumbersome way for ensuring that the vertical glue between baselines of two lines of text, e.g. at a paragraph break, is always an integer multiple of `\baselineskip` - even if phrases are of different font size?

   [image]
3. What is the best/least cumbersome way for ensuring that the vertical glue between baselines of two lines of text, e.g. at a paragraph break, is always an integer multiple of `\baselineskip` - even if phrases are of different font sizesand  phrases typeset in two different font sizes are aligned so that rules that delimit the top of ascenders of the letters of the larger font are at the height of the rules that delimit the top of the ascenders of the smaller font?

   [image]

I only found cumbersome ways for achieving such things where "manual tweaking" and weird primitive instructions need to be written directly into the file holding the text of the document. I did not yet find ways of implementing methods for achieving such things as macros that might be provided as a private separate package where usage of these methods/macros would not be cumbersome as well. I'd like to learn to write LaTeX code for having LaTeX do such things automatically while processing the file holding the text of the document - without me needing to intersperse the actual texts of my documents with tons of weird instructions for switching typesetting mode from horizontal mode to restricted horizontal mode or vertical mode or for creating and measuring boxes or for undoing some `\lineskip` with `\vbox`es/`\vtop`s of a height/depth that exceeds `\baselineskip` so that vertical distance to subsequent lines is below `\lineskiplimit`, ...

As with TeX⁠ ⁠-⁠ ⁠LaTeX Stack Exchange demanding complete minimal reproducible examples is a reflex even in situations where it is not about fixig code, but is about asking for best practise while code of one who has to ask about best practise is likely not to exhibit best practise, I show what I did so far. I hope that this also satisfies those who in their distrust demand from questioners a guesture of self-humiliation in the form of not just saying that they already spent a considerable timespan on struggling with the matter without real success, but also delivering code snippets that form bad and poorly written code which is of no real use for anyone and only might serve the purpose of refuting the insinuation that they had lied when saying that they already spent a considerable timespan on struggling.

I did 1. in the following cumbersome way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newsavebox\mynormalbox
\newsavebox\myhugebox

\begin{document}

\savebox\mynormalbox{\hbox{\normalsize Text}}%
\savebox\myhugebox{\hbox{\huge Text}}%
Text Text \lower\dimexpr\ht\myhugebox-\ht\mynormalbox\relax\hbox{\huge Text Text} Text Text

\end{document}
```

I did 2. in the following cumbersome way:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\noindent %\leavevmode
\vbox to 12\baselineskip{%
  \hbox{line 001}%
  \hbox{line 002}%
  \hbox{line 003}%
  \hbox{line 004}%
  \hbox{line 005}%
  \hbox{line 006}%
  \hbox{line 007}%
  \hbox{line 008}%
  \hbox{line 009}%
  \hbox{line 010}%
  \hbox{line 011}%
  \hbox{line 012}%
} 
\vrule{}
\vbox to 12\baselineskip{%
  \hbox{line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1}%
  \vskip-\lineskip
  \vbox to 3\baselineskip{\vfill\hbox{Line 2 Line 2 {\huge Line 2} Line 2 Line 2}}%
  \hbox{line 3 line 3 line 3 line 3 line 3 line 3}%
  \vskip-\lineskip
  \vbox to 3\baselineskip{\vfill\hbox{Line 4 Line 4 {\huge Line 4} Line 4 Line 4}}%
  \hbox{line 5 line 5 line 5 line 5 line 5 line 5}%
  \vskip-\lineskip
  \vbox to 3\baselineskip{\vfill\hbox{Line 6 Line 6 {\huge Line 6} Line 6 Line 6}}%
}%
\end{document}
```

I did 3. in the following cumbersome way:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newsavebox\mynormalbox
\newsavebox\myhugebox

\begin{document}
\noindent %\leavevmode
\vbox to 16\baselineskip{%
  \vfill
  \hbox{\strut line 001}%
  \hbox{line 002}%
  \hbox{line 003}%
  \hbox{line 004}%
  \hbox{line 005}%
  \hbox{line 006}%
  \hbox{line 007}%
  \hbox{line 008}%
  \hbox{line 009}%
  \hbox{line 010}%
  \hbox{line 011}%
  \hbox{line 012}%
  \hbox{line 013}%
  \hbox{line 014}%
  \hbox{line 015}%
  \hbox{line 016\strut}%
  \vfill
} 
\vrule{}
\vbox to 16\baselineskip{%
  \vfill
  \savebox\mynormalbox{\hbox{\normalsize line1234567890}}%
  \savebox\myhugebox{\hbox{\huge  line1234567890}}%
  \hbox{\strut line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1 line 1}%
  \vtop to 3\baselineskip{%
    \hbox{\vphantom{line2}}%
    \hbox{line 2 line 2 \lower\dimexpr\ht\myhugebox-\ht\mynormalbox\relax\hbox{\huge line 2} line 2 line 2}%
    \vfill
  }%
  \vskip-\lineskip
  \hbox{line 3 line 3 line 3 line 3 line 3 line 3}%
  \vtop to 3\baselineskip{%
    \hbox{line 4 line 4 \lower\dimexpr\ht\myhugebox-\ht\mynormalbox\relax\hbox{\huge line 4} line 4 line 4}%
    \vfill
  }%
  \vskip-\lineskip
  \hbox{line 5 line 5 line 5 line 5 line 5 line 5}%
  \vbox to 3\baselineskip{%
    \vfill
    \hbox{\lower-\lineskip\hbox{line 6 line 6 {\huge line 6} line 6 line 6}}%
  }%
  \vskip-\lineskip
  \hbox{line 7 line 7 line 7 line 7 line 7 line 7}%
  \vbox to 2\baselineskip{%
    \vfill
    \hbox{\lower-\lineskip\hbox{line 8 line 8 {\huge line 8} line 8 line 8}}%
  }%
  \vskip-\lineskip
  \hbox{line 9 line 9 line 9 line 9 line 9 line 9\strut}%
  \vfill
}%
\end{document}
```

(With 2. and 3. "line 001", "line 002" etc at the left are only to show that the baselines of the lines at the right have vertical distances that are multiples of `\baselineskip` of the normalfont in normalsize.)

Comment: I don't know if one of the ways of accomplishing things that I can imagine is the least cumbersome way. Asking for minimal complete reproducible example also serves the purpose of getting to know what aspects, routines, macros, parameters, packages and terminology of (La)TeX the questioner already delved into and thus already has learned about and what aspects might require more detailed explanation. So asking for mcre might not be about humiliation but about estimating the questioner's knowledge.